# Also order when Qty is 0

Tags: magento-1.9, backorder, qty-increment

Is there a possibility when the stock is 0, people can still place an order and that it will be a backorder.

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable backorder, Check following point.

1. Configure Magento to allow customers to purchase out of stock products, this can be done as a global setting in `system > configuration > Catalog > inventory` or per product

[image]

2. Mark the product as **“In stock”** which you want to show as Backorder on frontend. This can be done from inventory tab under product management.

[image]
Hope it helps you

Comment: Hello Rohit, I now but It need also to work when the QTY is 0 and not below 0 .